# AngularJS - iterating through a model and comparing with keys

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

So this is an example of what I have:

```
scope.exampleModel{
    var1: 'data1',
    var2: 'data2'
}

_.each(scope.exampleModel, function(detail) {
      if(*key* == 'var1'){
          scope.answer = detail
      }
});
```

I need to iterate through the model and find the key that I want and then when I do, I want to let scope.answer equal to the value of that key.
I've tried "if(detail.key == "var1"){ ... }" but that doesn't work.

Comment: You pass the key as the second parameter of the `each` callback: `_.each(scope.exampleModel, function(detail, key) {`

Answer (score 0):

Check angular forEach documentation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

You can retrieve the key if you define the second parameter. Like this:

```
angular.forEach(scope.exampleModel, function(value, key) {
    if(key == 'var1') {
        scope.answer = value;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple version using plain js:

```
exampleModel = {
   var1: 'data1',
   var2: 'data2'
}

for(p in exampleModel) {
    if(p == 'var1'){
        vm.answer = detail
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you. Thanks.